# How can I check if two Map objects are equal?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How can I check if two [ES2015 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects have the same set of `(key, value)` pairs?

We can assume that all the keys and values are primitive datatypes.

One approach to solve this would be to take the `map.entries()`, create array from it, then sort that array by keys. And do the same thing with the other map. And then loop through those two arrays to compare them. All this seams cumbersome and also very inefficient because of sorting (performance inefficiency) and because of making those arrays (memory inefficiency).

Does anybody have better idea?

Comment: provide code not links

Comment: Provide code for what?

Comment: Your question. you have to attempt to find a solution yourself before you ask. its in the rules. you must provide code examples of what you have tried so far

Comment: Either implement a deep comparison or use an existing implementation https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Comment: Or you could create your own function to iterate through two maps and compare them. That's what I would do but I would like to see the poster at least attempt something before we show them how to do it.

Comment: Are the `value`s or keys in these Maps objects or arrays?  If not, it's pretty easy.  If so, then you need a deep recursive comparison for objects/arrays.  And, when you want to compare two objects for equality, are you looking to see they are actually the same object or that they just contain the same properties?

Comment: @DustinPoissant it is not a problem to write a several for loops to loop through the keys and values, and I can easily detect if those two maps are equal that way. But it appears too cumbersome to me to do that. I would like to know what if there is some standard, or best way to compare two maps

Comment: @DustinPoissant your interest in pedagogy is commendable, but deep equality check is a difficult problem. Everybody should be warned of the disasters that can arise by trying to implement a solution unwittingly instead of relying on peer-reviewed, constantly updated implementations such as [lodash's _.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)

Comment: There is no  standard way of doing this.  Your options are to find a library that does it or implement it yourself.  As several of us have said, if you're trying to do deep object comparison for property equality, that is a tricky proposition fraught with issues of circular references, special objects like `Date` that require special means of comparing and such.  If it's just string, number or boolean values, then it's not so difficult.  As your question stands now, it doesn't say whether you're just trying to solve the easy case or if the hard case of nested objects is required.

Comment: @jfriend00, initially I wanted to know the answer for both cases, so I didn't want to specify anything specific in the question... Let's assume that maps have only primitive values as keys and values

Comment: As I said, there is no standard mechanism for that comparison.  Since it sounds like you already know how to make such a comparison, I'd suggest you write that code and come back here if you get stuck.  We generally don't just write code based on a spec here until you've tried and got stuck somewhere.

Comment: @ChristopheMarois I agree that the "proper" way to do this would be to "not" do it and let a framework handle it for you. But the question was "how do I do this". And I feel if for no other reason than for the sake of learning we should attempt an answer rather than just reply "dont do it, let a framework do it for you".

Comment: Technically he is not asking for a "deep" comparison. He is asking if they have the same set of key-value-pairs. So a "soft copy" or a "hard copy" would both have the same sets of key-value-pairs.

Comment: IMO this question is fine. This isn't a coding test; stating an algorithm that works (which you did) and asking if there's a more canonical one is fine. Nonetheless if you scratched out the code then people who vote without reading the question will think it's better and you would get people off your back.

Comment: @jfriend00 IMO your detailed explanation of *why* there is not a "standard" solution and the cases the OP must consider is the best answer to this question. I would post it.

Comment: @djechlin - Per your suggestion, I put my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is no "standard" or "built-in" way to do this.  Conceptually, you just have to compare that the two Map objects have the same keys and values for each key and have no extra keys.

To be as efficient about the comparison as possible, you can do the following optimizations:

1. First check the `.size` property on both maps.  If the two maps don't have the same number of keys, then you know right away, they can't be identical.
2. Furthermore, guaranteeing that they have the same number of keys allows you to just iterate one of the maps and compare its values to the other.
3. Use the `for (var [key, val] of map1)` iterator syntax for iterating the keys so you don't have to build or sort an array of keys yourself (should be both faster and more memory efficient).
4. Then, lastly, if you make sure that the comparison returns immediately as soon as a mismatch is found, then it will shorten the execution time when they are not the same.

Then, since `undefined` is a legal value in a Map, but it's also what `.get()` returns if the key is not found, we have to watch out for that by doing an extra `.has()` if the value we're comparing is `undefined`.

Since both keys and values with a Map object can be objects themselves, this gets much trickier if you want a deep property comparison of objects to determine equality rather than just the more simple `===` that Javascript uses by default to test for the same object.  Or, if you're only interested in objects that have primitives for keys and values, then this complexity can be avoided.

For a function that tests only strict value equality (checks objects to see if they are the same physical object, not a deep property comparison), you can do what is shown below.  This uses ES6 syntax for efficient iteration of the map objects and attempts to improve performance when they do not match by short circuiting and returning `false` as soon as a mismatch is found.

```js
"use strict";

function compareMaps(map1, map2) {
    let testVal;
    if (map1.size !== map2.size) {
        return false;
    }
    for (let [key, val] of map1) {
        testVal = map2.get(key);
        // in cases of an undefined value, make sure the key
        // actually exists on the object so there are no false positives
        if (testVal !== val || (testVal === undefined && !map2.has(key))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// construct two maps that are initially identical
const o = {"k" : 2}

const m1 = new Map();
m1.set("obj", o);
m1.set("str0", undefined);
m1.set("str1", 1);
m1.set("str2", 2);
m1.set("str3", 3);

const m2 = new Map();
m2.set("str0", undefined);
m2.set("obj", o);
m2.set("str1", 1);
m2.set("str2", 2);
m2.set("str3", 3);

log(compareMaps(m1, m2));

// add an undefined key to m1 and a corresponding other key to m2
// this will pass the .size test and even pass the equality test, but not pass the
// special test for undefined values
m1.set("str-undefined", undefined);
m2.set("str4", 4);
log(compareMaps(m1, m2));

// remove one key from m1 so m2 has an extra key
m1.delete("str-undefined");
log(compareMaps(m1, m2));

// add that same extra key to m1, but give it a different value
m1.set("str4", 5);
log(compareMaps(m1, m2));

function log(args) {
    let str = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "object") {
            str += JSON.stringify(arguments[i]);
        } else {
            str += arguments[i];
        }
    }
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = str;
    const target = log.id ? document.getElementById(log.id) : document.body;
    target.appendChild(div);
}
```

---

If you wanted to do deep object comparison rather than just comparing to see if they are physically the same object, where values could be objects or arrays, then life gets a lot more complicated.

To do that, you need a deep object comparison method that takes into account all of the following:

1. Recursive comparison for nested objects
2. Protection against circular references (which can cause an infinite loop)
3. Knowledge of how to compare some types of built-in objects such as a `Date`.

Since a lot has been written elsewhere about how to do a deep object comparison (including a number of highly voted answers here on StackOverflow), I will assume that is not the main part of your question.

Comment: Why do you loop twice? Shouldn't just first loop suffice as you have already checked that the sizes match?

Comment: @contrabit - Good point.  I initially didn't have the `.size` comparison in there so I needed the second loop to handle extra keys in `m2`, but now that I have the `.size` comparison, I think you're right.  I will remove the second loop.

Comment: Added a check for an edge case if a value in a Map is `undefined` itself where the first version of the code would match that with a missing key because that's what `.get()` returns when the key is missing.

Comment: Good! This is obviously memory efficient. I will try to compare performance of yours and my approach for a lot of data.

Comment: Added another test case for the special `undefined` value issue.

Comment: @DoAsync - That is correct and it was never designed to compare order as most uses of a Map object only care about what's in the Map, not what order things were inserted.  If you wanted to compare order, then you would do this differently.  Please note that the QUESTION asked here was ***"How can I check if two ES2015 Map objects have the same set of (key, value) pairs?"*** which is what this answers.  No mention is made of insertion order anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a one-liner function for checking map equality:

```
const mapsAreEqual = (m1, m2) => m1.size === m2.size && Array.from(m1.keys()).every((key) => m1.get(key) === m2.get(key));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `Map` has ***only*** string keys, then you can use this approach to compare them:

```
const mapToObj = (map) => {
  let obj = Object.create(null)
  for (let [k,v] of map) {
    // We don’t escape the key '__proto__'
    // which can cause problems on older engines
    obj[k] = v
  }
  return obj
}

assert.deepEqual(mapToObj(myMap), myExpectedObj)
```

**Note:** `deepEqual` is part of many testing suites and if not, you can use lodash/underscore equivalents. Any function that does a deep comparison will do.

`mapToObj` function courtesy of http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_maps-sets.html

Answer (score 0):

The above won't work for `Map<string, object>` as in the following line will not evaluate two objects properly:

`if (testVal !== val || (testVal === undefined && !map2.has(key))) {`

The following version extends the function for `Map<string, object>` by comparing using JSON.stringify()

```
function compareMaps(map1, map2) {
    var testVal;
    if (map1.size !== map2.size) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var [key, val] of map1) {
        testVal = map2.get(key);
        // in cases of an undefined value, make sure the key
        // actually exists on the object so there are no false positives
        if (JSON.stringify(testVal) !== JSON.stringify(val) || (testVal === undefined && !map2.has(key))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to work for objects, as the question states "keys and values are primitive datatypes"

Comment: btw, if you want to add constraint for objects, then neither you code works. try to put two different functions as properties of the two objects against the same key.

Comment: Besides that the OP says values are primitives, `JSON.stringify(obj)` is not canonical for comparing objects because there's no guarantee that the properties on the object are in the same order in the JSON.  An actual depth comparison of an object involves more than this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example with the ability to provide an optional compare function

```
/**
 * The utility function that returns an intersection of two Sets
 *
 * @returns an array of items in common
 */
function intersection<T>(a: Set<T>, b: Set<T>): T[] {
  return Array.from(a).filter(x => b.has(x));
}

/**
 * Compares two Maps
 *
 * @param compare is an optional function for values comparison
 * @returns `true` if they are equal, and `false` otherwise
 */
function compareMaps<T>(a: Map<string, T>, b: Map<string, T>, compare?: (aValue: T, bValue: T) => boolean): boolean {
  const common = intersection(new Set(a.keys()), new Set(b.keys()));
  return a.size === b.size && 
    common.length === a.size && 
    common.every(key => 
      compare?.(a.get(key) as T, b.get(key) as T) ?? a.get(key) === b.get(key));
```

}

Answer (score -4):

Note that the solution proposed by @jfriend00 does not work in typescript ES2016. See this for the right answer: [iteration over a typescript map failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520050/iteration-over-a-typescript-map-failing/45525532#45525532)