# iteration over a typescript map failing

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator

I'm using the function below to compare two maps. What's interesting is that the code inside for loop is never executed. So, `console.log(key,val)` code is never executed. Of course I made sure that the maps I'm comparing are not empty and are of same size to force execution of the code inside the for loop. Am I making a really silly mistake or am missing a deep concept?

```
private compareMaps(map1, map2) {
        var testVal;
        if (!(map1 && map2)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map1.size !== map2.size) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var [key, val] of map1) {
            testVal = map2.get(key);
            console.log(key, val);
            if (testVal !== val || (testVal === undefined && !map2.has(key))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: in javascript, it is working.

Answer (score 8):

> What's interesting is that the code inside for loop is never executed. Am I making a really silly mistake or am missing a deep concept?

You're missing the fact that...

#### `for...of` does not work on `Map` in TypeScript prior to ES6

When it targets ECMAScript prior to ES6, the TypeScript compiler transpiles the `for...of` statement into a `for` loop.

This code:

```
for (var [key, val] of map) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Becomes this code:

```
for (var _i = 0, map_1 = map; _i < map_1.length; _i++) {
    var _a = map_1[_i], key = _a[0], val = _a[1];
    console.log(key);
}
```

What to do?

**Option 1**: When we must target ECMAScript prior to ES6, the `forEach` function can be a suitable alternative to the `for...of` loop. Beware though that `forEach` has subtle differences from `for...of` (e.g. exiting early, async/await).

```
map.forEach((val, key) => { 
    console.log(key + ":" + val);
});
```

**Option 2**: When we must target ECMAScript prior to ES6, and we must have the exact behavior of `for...of`, the [answer by John Weisz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525426/1108891) makes sense: convert the `Map` to an `Array` and iterate the `Array` with `for...of`.

**Option 3**: When we can target [ECMAScript ES6 or later](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), use the `for...of` loop directly on the `Map`.

#### Aside: Map Equality

If the requirement is Map equality, consider [the `every` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). That takes care of the need to `break` in the iteration, because `every` immediately returns when it finds the first `false`.

**If order matters** to the comparison, use `every` like this:

```
function areEqual<K,V>(map1: Map<K,V>, map2: Map<K,V>) { 
    if(!map1 || !map2) return false;
    const array1 = Array.from(map1.entries());
    const array2 = Array.from(map2.entries());
    return array1.every(([k1, v1], index) => {
        const [k2, v2] = array2[index];
        return k1 === k2 && v1 === v2;
    });
}
```

**If order does not matter**, then we want set equality; use `every` like this:

```
function areSetEqual<K, V>(map1: Map<K, V>, map2: Map<K, V>) { 
    if(!map1 || !map2) return false;
    const array1 = Array.from(map1.entries());
    const array2 = Array.from(map2.entries());
    return array1.length === array2.length &&
        array1.every(([k1, v1]) => map2.get(k1) === v1);
}
```

Here is a demo of the functions in action:

```
const map1 = new Map([["key1", "val1"], ["key2", "val2"]]);
const map2 = new Map([["key1", "val1"], ["key2", "val2"]]);
const map3 = new Map([["key2", "val2"], ["key1", "val1"]]);

console.log(areEqual(map1, map2)); // true
console.log(areEqual(map1, map3)); // false
console.log(areSetEqual(map1, map2)); // true
console.log(areSetEqual(map1, map3)); // true
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using map. I printed the maps I'm comparing and this is how they look like: `Map(5) {"gender" => "men", "category" => "D", "1" => "11", "2" => "21", "3" => "32"}` and  `Map(5) {"gender" => "men", "category" => "D", "1" => "11", "2" => "21", "3" => "33"}`

Comment: @JohnWeisz Thank you. I have found the problem.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin forEach does work but mysteriously the forEach keep executing even after it encounters a return statement. So, a return statement inside forEach doesn't stop it.

Comment: @quantdaddy -- No, a `return` statement inside a `forEach` callback is essentially identical to `continue` in a loop, and there is no `break` equivalent directly.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Any logic behind that? return statement is always meant to stop running the block of code right?

Comment: @quantdaddy -- Of course, you are exiting the callback function at that point. Since the callback function is called for every iteration, exiting will allow the internal `forEach` implementation to carry on with calling your callback for the next item in the map, which is functionally identical to a `continue` statement inside a loop.

Comment: So, the forEach is not equivalent to running a for loop. I didn't know that. Does each callback runs independently in a separate thread? Return statement is not being executed inside the original block of code otherwise it will stop running.

Comment: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 2):

A `for ... of` loop can go through an *iterable*, and `Map<K, V>` by itself is not an iterable. You can convert it to an iterable using either the `keys`, `values`, or `entries` method (which you can then further convert to an array).

For example, to get an array representing your Map keys in insertion order, you can:

```
let keys = Array.from(map1.keys());
```

You can then iterate over this `keys` array using a `for ... of` loop, because an array is an iterable:

```
for (var key of keys) {
    testVal = map2.get(key);
    console.log(key, val);

    if (testVal !== val || (testVal === undefined && !map2.has(key))) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Interestingly though, I believe it *should* be possible to achieve this without having to create arrays, i.e. simply use `for (let key of map1.keys())`, as `.keys()` returns an iterable by itself, but TypeScript seems to have problems handling that (at least in ES5, didn't try in ES6 target).

Comment: If I'm comparing the entries of two maps, may be I can use map2.get("key") to get the value of the second map in each iteration. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working in typescript if I'm comparing two maps with string key and value.

```
private compareMaps(map1, map2) {
        var testVal;
        if (!(map1 && map2)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map1.size !== map2.size) {
            return false;
        }
        for (let key of Array.from(map1.keys())) {
            let val = map1.get(key);
            testVal = map2.get(key);
            if (testVal !== val || (testVal === undefined && !map2.has(key))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```