# Compare 2 maps in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, maps

i want to ask if it's possible to do this:

```
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set('1', "led");
map1.set('2', "zeppelin");

const map2 = new Map();
map2.set('1', "led");
map2.set('2', "floyd");
```

I want to compare these 2 maps.
I want to have a console.log() with the deferences of the maps.

Finally if the maps are the same and i add in map1 a new set

```
map1.set('3', "plant");
```

I want a log to tell me which is the new pair of kay-val

Thank you

Comment: Maybe related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948335/how-can-i-check-if-two-map-objects-are-equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set('1', "led");
map1.set('2', "zeppelin");

const map2 = new Map();
map2.set('1', "led");
map2.set('2', "floyd");

let isSame = true;
map1.forEach(function(val, key){
    if(map2.get(key) != val){
    console.log('map1.'+key+' = '+val +' | map2.' + key + ' = 
'+map2.get(key));
    isSame = false;
    }
})
if(isSame){
    map1.set('3', "plant"); 
    map1.forEach(function(val, key){
        console.log('map1.'+key+' => '+val);
    })
}
```

Comment: Please note: your solution does not strictly compare values so `1` and `"1"` would be considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution using [`Map#entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

This solutions checks that the supplied parameters are actually Maps and immediately returns `false` if the size does not match. Only if all those checks are passed an actual comparison of each key and value within the `Map` is performed which will greatly improved the [amortized runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis). In worst case the runtime will be `O(n)` with `n` being the number of key-value pairs in `map1`.

Comparison of keys and values is done on basis of [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) meaning that no deep comparison of arrays or objects is done. One could use [`lodash#isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) if that is a requirement. For the given example that is not necessary.

```js
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set("1", "led");
map1.set("2", "zeppelin");

const map2 = new Map();
map2.set("1", "led");
map2.set("2", "floyd");

const map3 = new Map();
map3.set("1", "led");
map3.set("2", "zeppelin");

function areEqual(map1, map2) {
  // early outs
  if(!(map1 instanceof Map) || !(map2 instanceof Map) || map1.size !== map2.size) return false;
  // we know we have to maps with the same amount of keys and values. Now compare them
  return [...map1.entries()].every(([key, value]) => (map2.has(key) && map2.get(key) === value));
}


console.log(areEqual(map1, map2));
console.log(areEqual(map1, map3));
```